# How can I run stacks tests with valgrind?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could run this, but then I'm also instrumenting all the cmake calls

```
valgrind --trace-children=yes --trace-children-skip="/opt/*" make test
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54239/how-can-i-run-stacks-tests-with-valgrind?/) by [Daniel Pinyol](https://answers.ros.org/users/470/daniel-pinyol/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a tutorial for launching things with valgrind [here](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0